# jQuery change values before form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change form field value before submitting it
currently am using jQuery keyup even for that

```
jQuery("#formID").keyup(function (event) {
    // do changes to form fields here before submit
}).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        // event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

But problem is it works when submit button is clicked but if user press enter then it not works.

So any idea that I can send changed values of form before submit by enter key pressed

Comment: just use the `submit` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event on `<form>` which will work for both form submit and Enter key press

```
jQuery("#formID").on('submit', function() {
    // Code here
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked :) actually i forgot async: false,  in my ajax request , although i tried that earlier